# Updating existing customer's card information with Stripe, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I have existing customers in Stripe and I want them to be able to attach a payment source (card) to their accounts if they so choose. I went through the Stripe docs, so this is what I have right now:

**stripe_controller.rb**

```
def update_source
  @user = current_user

  Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_"

  # find customer
  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.customer_id)

  # get token from stripe
  token = params[:stripeToken]

  # create and update source
  customer.sources.create({source: token})
  customer.default_source = token
  customer.save

  if customer.save
    redirect_to @user
  end
end
```

**_stripe.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_');

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
</script>
```

**edit_source.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: update_source_path(@user), :html => {:id => "payment-form"}) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    Card number
    <input class="text-field" type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
  </div>
  ...
  ...
  ...
<% end %>
```

I'm getting an error `Stripe::InvalidRequestError (Missing required param: source.)` I don't think it's creating a `source` or even grabbing the `token` from Stripe. Not sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: At first glance the code looks okay --- In your controller can you log `params[:stripeToken]` --- in your front-end  JS can you add some `console.log` statements around token creation --- does token creation happen as you expect, does a token make it to your backend. If you review your API logs in your Stripe Dashboard what do you see --- a lack of the token when creating a source on a customer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using card instead of source in the update_source action

```
# create and update source
card = customer.sources.create(card: stripe_token)
card.save
customer.default_card = card.id
customer.save
```